# driver.get() is not working for Android Native browser in Bluestack

Tags: appium, android-browser, bluestacks

Following is the desired capability i am using

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
 capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
 //capabilities.setCapability("avd","firstavd");
 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
 driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

When i execute the following code - with the above desired cap

```
  driver.navigate().to(url);
  driver.findElementByLinkText("Start").click();
```

It works absolutely fine in other avd. The browser is launched and the url is loaded. But in bluestacks I am getting the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: A request to switch to a different window could not be satisfied because the window could not be found.

Appium server:  info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":23,"value":{"message":"A request to switch to a different window could not be satisfied because the window could not be found.","origValue":"no such window: window was already closed\n  (Session info: webview=)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)"},"sessionId":"ba7131af61cad9451da99dd750d61fa8"}
```

What is wrong. I am not trying to switch any window. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: No Comment nothing. And a vote down !!! Great :-D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where exactly the problem is. But look at this http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.3.4/?java#about-appium. Linktext and partiallinktext is not supported by appium.

Comment: The problem is in the implementation of blue stacks i think. The line driver.get / driver.navigate() is not working. I had created an issue with appium as well.

Comment: no i think window is not found by appium. Can you post your entire code, doesn't seem like bug with appium.